# Neo4j delete a node property with neo4j-jdbc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, jdbctemplate, neo4j-java-api

I have an edge with sevral properties. I would like to keep the edge but remove only the name property.

My java Cypher is this :

```
public static final String DELETE_EDGE_PROPERTY_QUERY = //
        "MATCH ()-[r]->() where id(r) = {1} REMOVE r.{2} RETURN r"; //
```

It works on cypher console but doesn't work on jdbc.

I got this error :

> processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [MATCH ()-[r]->() where id(r) = {1} REMOVE r.{2} RETURN r]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Some errors occurred : 
>   [Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError]:Invalid input '{': expected an identifier, whitespace, a function name or a property key name (line 1, column 45 (offset: 44))
>   "MATCH ()-[r]->() where id(r) = {1} REMOVE r.{2} RETURN r"
>   `

Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT

I couldn't do with jdbc template.
so I have used String replacement:
Setting the property to NULL will delete the property
(http://www.baeldung.com/java-neo4j)

Solution : 
Java :

```
String deleteQuery = String.format(DELETE_EDGE_PROPERTY_QUERY, property);
plantJdbcTemplate.update(deleteQuery, edgeId);
```

cypher :

```
public static final String DELETE_EDGE_PROPERTY_QUERY = //
        "MATCH ()-[r]->() where id(r) = {1} SET r.%s = NULL RETURN r";
```

Comment: You may need to use the property name like `{:id}` instead of indexes.

Comment: Hey RP, thanks for replying. Are you sure? I want to remove the property itself and not it's value. Example : Edge (name = blabla, date = 1981,  degree = 5)  Hre I want to remove name and not blabla

Comment: I think it should be something like this `MATCH ()-[r]->() where id(r) = {:id} REMOVE r.name RETURN r`

Comment: indeed that' s what I did but here name should also be a param {:name} is passed as a property. I want to be able to remove any property(name, value, degree, age, etc)

Comment: May be a bug in the parser then, try using a string replacement to replace the property to be removed.

Comment: yeah It seems that neo4j-jdbc doesn't accept named properties {:id}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171727/discussion-between-rp-and-erectus).

Comment: RP, I have finally opted for String replacement and it seems to work. Thanks. I have EDIT my original post to add the solution

Comment: Nice, but you are not `REMOVE`ing the property? `NULL` are not recommended as per https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/remove/#remove-remove-a-property

Comment: indeed I just saw your link. I will probably change to REMOVE. I saw baeldung using NULL, that's why (http://www.baeldung.com/java-neo4j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a `neo4j-jdbc` issue, it's related to the design of Neo4j about parameterized query.

On a query you can parameterized all data you want, **except:**

- labels
- relationship types
- properties

If you want to do it in Cypher, there are a lot of helpers in the APOC plugin.